# Get android OS version table

Tags: android, version

My app is based on webview with js interface.
The js interface uses a hardcode table of all android OS versions.
I want to know if the android SDK includes something like that,i know I can get the device OS versions but I need a list of all the existing OS versions.

Answer (score 1):

[Build.VERSION_CODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) is the class you're looking for.

Comment: This class is OK but not good for release versions such as 4.4.2 for example,I need all the release versions.